# What is phpMyAdmin doing to my UNION ALL query?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, union

The following query returns 1 row:

```
SELECT `coach_id` FROM `table_a` WHERE `coach_id` = 8
UNION ALL
SELECT `coach_id` FROM `table_b` WHERE `coach_id` = 8
```

But `SELECT coach_id FROM table_b WHERE coach_id = 8` returns 2 rows.

And `SELECT coach_id FROM table_a WHERE coach_id = 8` returns 1 row.

I'm using `UNION ALL` to avoid the `DISTINCT` filtering, because I'm actually just interested in the total number of rows. Still it seems to behave like regular `UNION` a.k.a `UNION DISTINCT`.

Whats going on here? Query is executed in phpMyAdmin `4.5.2` interface on MariaDB `10.1.9` Server.

#### Update

I just discovered that the mysql command line client behaves like expected. So the failure has to be somewhere within my stack of `nginx 1.8.0`, `PHP 5.6.16` `mysqli` and `phpmyadmin`.

#### Update 2

When I run the query from a php script (using mysqli) it also correctly returns 3 rows. I guess that leaves nothing but phpMyAdmin to cause this phenomenon. Thanks for the help so far and sorry that the question has been misleading. I didn't know better...

Comment: The behavior you describe is not correct.  The query should be returning three rows.

Comment: That's why I'm so confused #.# Just discovered that the UNION ALL returns 2 rows when I swap the selects. So a bit like everything but the first line of the query would be ignored.

Comment: ^ However a normal UNION still removes duplicates in this case. So it does do something.

Comment: ok I was looking it up. Do you need to post more info, or change the question, idk. Because this isn't a mysql issue

Comment: This bug will be tracked at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11744

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a phpMyAdmin bug, which is fixed in v4.5.3.0 (2015-12-23).

Comment: I have 4.5.4.1 (2017) and it still can not execute UNION query

Answer (score 0):

### schema

```
create schema testThenDrop123;
use testThenDrop123; -- use that database

create table table_a
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    coach_id int not null
);

create table table_b
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    coach_id int not null
);

insert table_a (coach_id) values (8);
insert table_b (coach_id) values (8),(8);
```

### query

```
SELECT `coach_id` FROM `table_a` WHERE `coach_id` = 8 
UNION ALL 
SELECT `coach_id` FROM `table_b` WHERE `coach_id` = 8;
+----------+
| coach_id |
+----------+
|        8 |
|        8 |
|        8 |
+----------+
```

.

```
drop schema testThenDrop123; -- cleanup by dropping db
```

So I don't see what you are seeing.

Comment: Thank's for your effort. I just copy-paste tested your code and in fact it gives me the same inexplicable behavior. Only 1 row is returned. Any idea how I can go about debugging / investigating this? Who might be the culprit?

Comment: ^ ok the problem isn't mysql/MariaDB itself. The client works fine. (see update)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have dirty data? Spaces or some other character in with the ids? use LENGTH(coach_id), coach_id in your query. Then if it is more than one character it won't return those rows but you would know why.