# MySQL UNION ALL returning only the first table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very simple query - I want to get one column with all of the emails from table1(650 rows) and table2(550 rows):

```
SELECT email 
FROM table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT email 
FROM table2
```

The result has **650** rows, which is the number of rows in **table1**. The result should have **1200** rows- the actual sum of both tables' rows.

If I switch the SELECT statements' order - The result has **table2**'s rows - 550.

Any idea why this is happening?

I'm using PhpMyAdmin 4.5.1 with MariaDB 10.1.16 (MySQL)

Comment: I think this is a phpMyAdmin bug. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247531/what-is-phpmyadmin-doing-to-my-union-all-query

Answer (score 0):

Did some more research, Apparantly this is a phpMyAdmin bug.

See [What is phpMyAdmin doing to my UNION ALL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247531/what-is-phpmyadmin-doing-to-my-union-all-query)